# Parse JSON object in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, groovy

I'm  having some problems with parsing this json file. Seems like i'm having some problems with parsing the object-keyname and I'm not quite sure how to solve this.

My `JenkinsfileProperties.json` file looks like this:

```
{
   "predefines": {
        "69dA06x01": {
            "customer": "hello1",
            "label":    "test1",
            "opt":      true,
            "license": "baseline"
        },
        "69dR08x06": {
            "customer": "hello2",
            "label":    "test2",
            "opt":      true,
            "license": "baseline"
        }
    }
}
```

My groovy file looks like this:

```
conf = getJobConfiguration scm: scm, local: "checkout", file: "JenkinsfileProperties.json"

conf.predefines.each { predef ->
    builds["Build ${predef}"] = build(predef)
    lints["Lint ${predef}"] = lint(predef)
    unitTests["Unit Test ${predef}"] = unitTest(predef, predef.customer)
}
```

In my head `config.predefines.each { predef ->` will give me each instance of `69d....` along with its children. So accessing a child is simply the matter of doing `predef.customer` or `predef.label` etc.

Right now i get `No such field found: field java.util.AbstractMap$SimpleImmutableEntry customer.` What am I doing wrong?

I need to be able to iterate through the `69...` entries and I will also have to be able to get their value i.e. `69dA06x01`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Solved it like this

Key values (`69d...`) are accessed like this:
`predef.key`

The keys subentries are accessed like this:

```
predef.value["customer"]
predef.value["opt"]
predef.value["license"]
predef.value["label"]
```

All together:

```
conf.predefines.each { predef ->
    builds["Build ${predef.key}"] = build(predef)
    lints["Lint ${predef.key}"] = lint(predef)
    unitTests["Unit Test ${predef.key}"] = unitTest(predef, predef.value["customer"])
}
```

This works if the sub-entries are the same all the way, but i might see a scenario where all subentries are called different things in each `69d...` object. Fortunately this works for this scenario.